Help calculating a more nuanced solution to a simple probability riddle, where non-zero decision making time is taken into account.
A video explaining conditional probability used the following example:

You are poisoned and need to lick the female of a certain species of frog for the antidote. The male and female frogs are identical except that the males make a distinct croaking noise, while the females are always silent. In a clearing there is one frog on the left side and two on the right. You don't have time to lick all three, only either the one on the left or the two on the right. Without seeing which, one of the two frogs on the right croaks. Do you go left or right for the highest chance to survive?

The video gave the straightforward answer:  on the left, $\mathbb{P}(1 \text{ male}) = \frac 12$. On the right, conditional probability tells us
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(2 \text{ males} \mid \text{at least } 1 \text{ male}) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(2 \text{ males} \cap \text{at least }1\text{ male})}{\mathbb{P}(\text{at least }1 \text{ male})} =\frac {1/4}{3/4} = \frac 13,
\end{align*}
assuming males and females occur in equal proportions.

Someone pointed out, however, that there is a more nuanced answer taking into account the non-zero decision making time and the fact that two male frogs are more likely to croak again during that time than a single male frog. I assumed this would be a simple application of a Poisson distribution but upon trying to write it out I found my solution to be unsatisfactory and intuitively incorrect, so I think I made a mistake somewhere. This was my calculation:
Suppose the poison will kill you in $T$ minutes, and that the frogs croak $C$ times per minute on average. Assuming the croaking of a single frog is independent of the time since last croak (and ignoring that croaking is not an instantaneous process either etc.) we are dealing with a Poisson distribution with rate $TC$ in the time before you die. For the silent, single frog on the left we therefore have (I will use $m$ and $c$ as shorthand for male and croak respectively),
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(0c \mid 1m) = e^{-TC}.
\end{align}
Bayes' theorem then gives us
\begin{align}
\mathbb P (1m \mid 0c) &= \frac{\mathbb P(0c \mid 1m)\mathbb P(1m)}{\mathbb P(0c)} \\
&= \frac{e^{-TC}\cdot 1/2}{1/2 + e^{-TC}\cdot 1/2} = \frac{1}{e^{TC} + 1}.
\end{align}
On the right hand side, with the two frogs and a single croak, if the two frogs are both male we have the sum of two Poisson processes, which is a Poisson process with the rates summed. We therefore have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(1c \mid 2m) = 2TCe^{-2TC}.
\end{align}
Now Bayes' theorem gives
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(2m \mid 1c) = \frac{2TCe^{-2TC}\cdot 1/4}{TCe^{-TC}\cdot 1/2 + 2TCe^{-2TC}\cdot 1/4} = \frac{1}{e^{TC} + 1},
\end{align}
where I have used that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(1c) &= \mathbb P(1c \mid 0m)\mathbb P(0m) + \mathbb P(1c\mid 1m)\mathbb P(1m) + \mathbb P(1c \mid 2m)\mathbb P(2m) \\
&= 0\cdot 1/4 + TCe^{-TC}\cdot 1/2 + 2TCe^{-2TC}\cdot 1/4.
\end{align}
This seems incorrect to me for the following reasons:

It seems very strange that the left and right side end up having the same chance of survival. The whole point of the "simple solution" was that this is not the case.
I would expect that in the $T,C \rightarrow 0$ limits, the "more nuanced" answer would reduce to the same probabilities as the simple case. After all, the whole point of the nuanced answer was the non-zero decision making time. If the decision making time is zero, or waiting longer won't give any additional information anyway, this should lead to the original solution. This makes me suspect that the calculation for the two frogs is wrong, but I don't see where.

Where is my mistake?

I'm sure that the frog licking question was on a TED-ED video or something on YouTube. The problem in the comments was regarding the sample space of the two-frog clearing (this is a famous example in probability theory). I wonder if the source for the nuanced version is also in that comment section. (can't find the video)

Original TED-Ed YouTube: Can you solve the frog riddle? - Derek Abbott uses sample space ${MM,FM,MF}$ (equally likely) to get p=2/3. Response YouTube by MindYourDecisions: TED-Ed's Frog Riddle Is Wrong uses sample space ${M_0M_1,M_1M_0,FM_1,M_1F}$ (equally likely, where 0/1 denotes croaked/didn't croak) to get p=1/2.

Thank you, so this actually gives the same result I got in the $T,C\rightarrow 0$ cases. By considering the croaking over a period of time I was essentially forced to consider the second sample space.

There does not seem to be anything wrong with your calculations, but it is important to be careful in interpreting the results. What you set out to find is:

Given that you hear exactly one croak from the right group within a time period $T$, where male frogs croak with a mean rate of $C$, what is the probability that both right frogs are male?

This is subtly different from the original problem, which is in essence that

Given the right group contains a male, what is the probability that both right frogs are male?

Why are these questions different? In the former, the "evidence" is an occurrence of an event. You have the elapsed time over which the experiment was conducted $T$ as well as the mean rate of croaking $C$. In particular, the information you gained is that exactly one croak occurred during the time $T$. This certainly rules out the possibility of there being two females in the right group, but the way in which the probability is "divided" between 2 males and 1 male + 1 female depends on $C$ and $T$.
The case where $C T \gg 1$ represents a situation where we are likely to hear many croaks from each male. Hypotheses featuring fewer males become overwhelmingly more likely in the limit $C T \to \infty$, because a fixed number of croaks (namely, $1$) is observed.
On the other hand, the case where $C T \ll 1$ represents a situation where we more or less got lucky, since the observation time is short to expect a croak. In the limit as $C T \to 0$, a hypothesis featuring $N$ males becomes $N$ times more probable than one featuring a single male. In your case with $N = 2$, it so happens that the hypothesis 1 male + 1 female becomes equally probable as 2 males in the limit $C T \to 0$, because the latter hypothesis becoming $2$ times as probable to observe a case with a single male is canceled out by the fact that the former hypothesis has a multiplicity of $2$.
The important point is that the more nuanced problem you are considering has more information that you can use to perform Bayesian updating. You can imagine that the original (simplified) problem is the same as an oracle telling you that the right group contains a male. That oracle has essentially removed the information about the croak count. The best you can do, given that males and females are equally frequent in the population, is assign equal probabilities to each of the gender combinations (i.e., $\frac{1}{3}$ for each) after removing the possibility of 2 females.
An interesting question you could ask is

What non-dimensional time $C T^*$ makes it so that the observation of a single croak in a time interval $T^*$ gives no new information distinguishing between 1 male + 1 female and 2 males?

For this, we can simply set
$$\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{e^{C T^*} + 1} \implies C T^* = \ln 2$$
This means that if you listen for time $T^* = \frac{\ln 2}{C}$ and hear a single croak, then the two problems you have considered become identical.
